# What is the best hypothesis test method for a sample dataset with values less than 0.1?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, small-sample, treatment-effect, algorithmic-fairness

I have a dataset with attributes X, Y, W, and Z. X is the predictor, Y is the outcome, Z is the confounder and W is the mediator. I have defined 1 [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic) formula for each attribute denoted by f(X), f(Y), f(Z), and f(W). I have the following relationship between the satisfaction time of the formulas T(f(Z)) < T(f(X)) < T(f(W)) < T(f(Y)). This inequality constraint is for enforcing the precedence of cause and effect.

I have evaluated the truth value of these formulas using a real values time series dataset, hence I have a boolean dataset. Then I calculated the indirect effect, direct effect, and spurious effect for each time step. Now the values of my sample datasets are between -0.1 and 0.1. Also, my sample size is less than 10 (I have less than 10 time steps).
Take direct effect as an example, I want to test if there is disparate treatment or not. My null hypothesis is that there is no disparate treatment which is equivalent to saying that the average of the direct effects over time steps is zero. The alternative hypothesis is that the average is not zero. Since the values are already close to zero, the t-test using p-values did not do well at all. In other words, the p-values suggest that there is no disparate treatment while when I calculate the direct effect using the real-valued dataset, I do have disparate treatment.
Any advice on this matter would help a great deal.

Comment: A p-value will never "suggest" that the null hypothesis is true, all it can say is that there is no strong evidence in the data against the null hypothesis, which can easily happen with a small sample size. (I admit I haven't understood all that you're doing, but the point should stand anyway; if the information in your data is weak, you may not be able to say anything significant.)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any approach that can deal with values in the order of 0.1 and less?

Comment: “Values of 0.1 and less” is not a problem, you can multiply them by 1000 to make them “100 or less”, or transform them to any other scale. It's irrelevant.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your comment. It actually gave me a good insight into where I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Values of 0.1 and less" is irrelevant. It is just a matter of scaling the data. For example, if your data is in units like 0.1 kilometers, it is the same as 100 meters, i.e. 0.1 km $\times$ 1000.